# setTimout calling far too many times

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a setTimout loop being called repeatedly but the loop seems to catch up with itself and causes sticking on my page ect. I added a alert to see what was happening and i had the timer set to call every 10seconds, but the alert was being displayed oppressively faster until it was continuous

can anybody see why this is by my code below.

Many thanks

```
$(function(){
    var running = setTimeout(function (){ 
        var varLISTID = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-LISTID");  
        var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-USERACCOUNTNAME");
        var varITEMACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-ITEMACCOUNTNAME");
        var varSELECTEDUSER= document.getElementById('datacatchuser').getAttribute("data-variable-SELECTEDUSER");

        var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER;
        $('#infobox1').load(mylink);

        var myotherlink = "contactselect.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname=" + varUSERACCOUNTNAME + "&itemaccountname=" + varITEMACCOUNTNAME + "&selecteduser=" + varSELECTEDUSER; 
        $('#containercontact').load(myotherlink);
    },10000);//10s


    $(document).keypress(function() {
    clearInterval(running); 
    })


});
```

Comment: The code you posted presents no reason for the behavior you describe. You also talk about some alert, which is not present. Please update the snippet into a ***runnable*** [mcve] (use the `<>` button to add one).

Comment: There's no loop here. That must also be in the code you didn't post.

Comment: sorry, very new to all this.